# Typescript pushing object into array gets stuck without any error

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I am facing a weird behavior in one of my methods. It prints `entity to user`
 and `start loop` but after that nothing happens. It gets stuck somehow, without any errors!? It never reached `end loop` and ofcourse also not `finished`

I really don't know what is wrong with it. I am using similar things to convert from one type to another, but I am missing something here.

The method:

```
 entityToClientUser(users: any) {
    const clientUsers = [];
    console.log('entity to user');
    console.log(users);
    for (const u of users) {
      console.log('start loop');
      clientUsers.push(
        new ClientUser(
          u.id,
          u.username,
          u.email,
          '',
          '',
          u.description,
          false,
          u.registrationDate,
          new Date(),
          u.role.role ? u.role.role : 1
        )
      );
      console.log('end loop');
    }
    console.log('finished');
    console.log(clientUsers);
    return clientUsers;
  }
```

Object given to the method:

```
[ {
    id: 1,
    username: 'test',
    email: 'info@example.com',
    password: 'b234234c34899hwerwer4535rfa10a666edgfh43',
    avatar: null,
    ip: null,
    description: 'A simple user.',
    isGuest: null,
    lastAuth: null,
    registrationDate: 2019-10-31T23:56:14.170Z 
    } 
]
```

The ClientUser Class

```
export class ClientUser {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  avatar: string;
  ip: string;
  description: string;
  isGuest: boolean;
  lastAuth: Date;
  role: number;
  registrationDate: Date;

  constructor(id: number, username: string, email: string, avatar: string, ip: string, description: string, isGuest: boolean, registrationDate: Date, lastAuth: Date, role: number) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.avatar = avatar;
    this.ip = ip;
    this.description = description;
    this.isGuest = isGuest;
    this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
    this.lastAuth = lastAuth;
    this.role = role;
  }


}
```

Comment: I know you said there is no error being thrown but

`u.role.role` seems likely to throw an undefined error, since role is not defined in the user object.

Is that the case?

Comment: yes glneto is write ,that shoud be u.role not u.role.role

Comment: Yes that was the reason! But I don't understand why i was not getting any error in the console. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have users defined as any: `users: any`
Typescript won't warn you about anything being referenced on one of those user objects.

You would need to change that to `users: ClientUser[]` or some other shape that Typescript can evaluate.

In your case I would recommend doing:

ClientUserBase.ts

```
export class ClientUserBase {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  description: string;
  registrationDate: Date;
  role: number;
}
```

ClientUser.ts

```
//Inherits common properties from ClientUserBase
export class ClientUser extends ClientUserBase {
  avatar: string;
  ip: string;
  isGuest: boolean;
  lastAuth: Date;

  constructor(clientUserBase: ClientUserBase, avatar: string, ip: string, isGuest: boolean, lastAuth: Date) {
    this.id = clientUserBase.id;
    this.username = clientUserBase.username;
    this.email = clientUserBase.email;
    this.avatar = avatar;
    this.ip = ip;
    this.description = clientUserBase.description;
    this.isGuest = isGuest;
    this.registrationDate = clientUserBase.registrationDate;
    this.lastAuth = lastAuth;
    this.role = clientUserBase.role;
  }
```

Method that gets executed:

```
entityToClientUser(users: ClientUserBase[]) {
    const clientUsers: ClientUser[] = [];
    console.log('entity to user');
    console.log(users);
    for (const u of users) {
        console.log('start loop');
        clientUsers.push(new ClientUser(u, '', '', false, new Date()));
        console.log('end loop');
    }
    console.log('finished');
    console.log(clientUsers);
    return clientUsers;
}
```

Something like that anyway...